# Multiple Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, dependencyobject

I'm currently working on a user control and stuck with the custom  properties of the dependency object class
IsEnabled gets recognized but not FooText

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                   sc:TouchScrolling.IsEnabled = "true" 
                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
```

I need to set more properties on the sc:TouchScrolling element, but VS keeps complaining that it can't find the property.

TouchScrolling element inherits from Dependency Object

```
public class TouchScrolling : DependencyObject
    {
        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEnabledProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value); }
        }

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(TouchScrolling), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsEnabledChanged));


//FooText is not recognized
  public string FooText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(FooTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FooTextProperty, value); }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be missing the FooText DependencyProperty...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FooTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FooText", typeof(string), typeof(TouchScrolling), null);
```